# Return a stream from a function

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, state-management, riverpod

I am using riverpod for state management.

```
class SignInStateNotifier extends StateNotifier<SignInFormStates> {
  SignInStateNotifier(this._authFacade) : super(SignInFormStates.initial());

  final IAuthFacade _authFacade;

  void mapEventToState(SignInFormEvents signInFormEvents) {
    state = signInFormEvents.when(
        emailChanged: (value) => state.copyWith(
              emailAddress: EmailAddress(value),
              authFailureOrSuccess: none(),
            ),
        passwordChanged: (value) => state.copyWith(
              password: Password(value),
              authFailureOrSuccess: none(),
            ),
        signInWithEmailAndPasswordPressed: () async* {
          yield* _performActionOnAuthFacade(
              _authFacade.signInWithEmailAndPassword);
        });
  }
```

I get an error over here

```
signInWithEmailAndPasswordPressed: () async* {
              yield* _performActionOnAuthFacade(
                  _authFacade.signInWithEmailAndPassword);
            });
```

> The argument type 'Stream Function()' can't be
> assigned to the parameter type 'SignInFormStates Function()'.

My `__performActionOnAuthFacade` function

```
Stream<SignInFormStates> _performActionOnAuthFacade(
    Future<Either<AuthFailure, Unit>> Function({
      @required EmailAddress emailAddress,
      @required Password password,
    })
        forwardCall,
  ) async* {
    Either<AuthFailure, Unit> failureOrSuccess;
    if (state.emailAddress.isValid() && state.password.isValid()) {
      yield state.copyWith(
        isSubmitting: true,
        authFailureOrSuccess: none(),
      );
      failureOrSuccess = await _authFacade.registerWithEmailAndPassword(
          emailAddress: state.emailAddress, password: state.password);
    }
    yield state.copyWith(
        isSubmitting: false,
        showErrorMessage: true,
        authFailureOrSuccess: optionOf(failureOrSuccess));
  }
```

Please give a solution to solve this error. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this with `StateNotifier`, where is no need to use `Stream` for change state, you need to do something like this:

```
class SignInFormStateNotifier extends StateNotifier<SignInFormState> {
  final IAuthFacade _authFacade;

  SignInFormStateNotifier(this._authFacade) : super(SignInFormState.initial());

  Future handleEvent(SignInFormEvent event) async {
    event.map(
      // email changed
      emailChanged: (event) {
        state = state.copyWith(
          emailAddress: EmailAddress(event.email),
          authFailureOrSuccessOption: none(),
        );
      },
      // password changed
      passwordChanged: (event) {
        state = state.copyWith(
          password: Password(event.password),
          authFailureOrSuccessOption: none(),
        );
      },
      // register with email and password
      registerWithEmailAndPassword: (event) async {
        await _performActionWithEmailAndPassword(
          _authFacade.registerWithEmailAndPassword,
        );
      },
      // sign in with email and password
      signInWithEmailAndPassword: (event) async {
        await _performActionWithEmailAndPassword(
          _authFacade.signInWithEmailAndPassword,
        );
      },
      // sign in with Google
      signInWithGoogle: (event) async {
        state = state.copyWith(
          isSubmitting: true,
          authFailureOrSuccessOption: none(),
        );
        final result = await _authFacade.signInWithGoogle();

        state = state.copyWith(
          isSubmitting: false,
          authFailureOrSuccessOption: some(result),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future _performActionWithEmailAndPassword(
    Future<Either<AuthFailure, Unit>> Function({
      @required EmailAddress emailAddress,
      @required Password password,
    })
        action,
  ) async {
    Either<AuthFailure, Unit> result;
    final isEmailValid = state.emailAddress.isValid();
    final isPasswordValid = state.password.isValid();

    if (isEmailValid && isPasswordValid) {
      state = state.copyWith(
        isSubmitting: true,
        authFailureOrSuccessOption: none(),
      );

      result = await action(
        emailAddress: state.emailAddress,
        password: state.password,
      );

      state = state.copyWith(
        authFailureOrSuccessOption: some(result),
      );
    }
    state = state.copyWith(
      isSubmitting: false,
      showErrorMessages: true,
      authFailureOrSuccessOption: optionOf(result),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is working!! Thanks a lot, @Viacheslav. But can you please explain why this works and what is the reason we don't want to use stream and use a Future instead?

Comment: @PythonHub, it works, because you are using `StateNotifier` with Riverpod's `StateNotifierProvider`, I don't have much time to explain, because my english is not good. But I recommend you to watch Reso Coder's video "Flutter StateNotifier + Riverpod Tutorial"  [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3OdciTLjSNA&t=1404s&ab_channel=ResoCoder).
When you call `state = SomeState(...)`, the `Consumer` which is listening this `StateNotifierProvider` from `watch` method, triggers to rebuild widget tree.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will watch the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your `SignInFormStates` class but its not expecting in `signInWithEmailAndPasswordPressed` to call a Stream function, but an empty voidCallback perhaps?

```
state = signInFormEvents.when(
        emailChanged: (value) => state.copyWith(
              emailAddress: EmailAddress(value),
              authFailureOrSuccess: none(),
            ),
        passwordChanged: (value) => state.copyWith(
              password: Password(value),
              authFailureOrSuccess: none(),
            ),
        signInWithEmailAndPasswordPressed: () => () async* {  //so a SignInFormStates Function() calls your stream function
          yield* _performActionOnAuthFacade(
              _authFacade.signInWithEmailAndPassword);
        });
```

But still there is a chance after that it will give you some other error telling you state is expecting to be of type `SignInFormStates` and you pass it a stream function, or maybe it actually waits the stream to finish and return the new state yielded, the only thing to do is try and see what happens